# Solaris 11.3 Extended Privilege Profile execve return EOVERFLOW

Tags: security, solaris, privileges

I'm getting the following error when running `java` with a profile with a long list of `file_read` extended attributes:

```
# pfexec /usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/bin/java -cp /vagrant HelloWorld
/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/bin/java: Value too large for defined data type
```

When I run it with `truss` I see the exec error message is:

```
execve("/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/bin/java", 0xFCEA4B60, 0xFCEA4B74) Err#79 EOVERFLOW
```

The man page for [execve](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E53394_01/html/E54765/execve-2.html) doesn't list `EOVERFLOW` as a possible return.

It appears to be related to the number of `file_read` extended attributes that I place in the profile. Here's how to reproduce the issue. The `HelloWorld.java` source is trivial but useful to ensure the privileges are assigned properly from `ppriv -v pid`

```
public class HelloWorld {
  public static void main( String[] args ) {
    System.out.println("Sleeping");
    try {
      Thread.sleep(50000);
    } catch( Exception e ) {
    }
    System.out.println("Hello World");
  }
}
```

There appears to be a bug in the `profiles` command as well as the `profiles` command was unwilling to generate a large enough list of `file_read` at
tributes. In order to create the profile, you must edit the resulting `/etc/security/exec_attr` as follows:

```
# profiles -p test 'set desc=testing; add cmd=/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/bin/java; set privs=basic; end; commit'
# usermod -P+test root
```

Manually edit `/etc/security/exec_attr` and use the following for the minimal permission set for `java` to execute without any permissions errors (backslashes added for readability and are allowed within the `exec_attr` file):

```
test:solaris:cmd:::/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/bin/java:privs=\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libc.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libcryptoutil.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libdl.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libdoor.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libelf.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libgen.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libkstat.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libm.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libm.so.2,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libmp.so.2,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libnsl.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libnvpair.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libscf.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libsocket.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libthread.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libucrypto.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libuutil.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/lib/amd64/libz.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/proc/*,\
{file_read}\:/system/volatile/name_service_door,\
{file_read}\:/system/volatile/tzsync,\
{file_read}\:/tmp,\
{file_read}\:/tmp/hsperfdata_root,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/bin/java,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/jvm.cfg,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/libjava.so,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/libverify.so,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/libzip.so,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/ext,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/ext/meta-index,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/meta-index,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/resources.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/jre/lib/rt.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/lib/amd64/jli/libjli.so,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/amd64/libCrun.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/amd64/libdemangle.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/amd64/libsched.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/amd64/libsmbios.so.1,\
{file_read}\:/usr/share/lib/zoneinfo/US/Eastern,\
{file_read}\:/vagrant/HelloWorld.class;limitprivs=file_read
```

In order to produce the error I added `{file_read}\:/absolute/path` entries until the error was generated. I used pre-existing files by generated by calling `find /usr/lib -name '*.jar'` and adding them until it failed with `EOVERFLOW`

In my case the following list of files was enough. Removing any of them was enough for it to work again.

```
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/authentication.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/authentication_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/config.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/config_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/container.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/container_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/control.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/control_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/dlmgr.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/dlmgr_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/errors.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/errors_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/evscntl.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/evscntl_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/files.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/files_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/kstat.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/kstat_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/modules.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/modules_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/network.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/network_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/pam.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/pam_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/panels.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/panels_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/rad.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/smf.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/smf_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/smf_old.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/smf_old_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/time.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/time_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/usermgr.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/usermgr_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/zfsmgr.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/zfsmgr_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/zonemgr.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/zonemgr_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/zonesbridge.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/zonesbridge_1.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/inventory/engines.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/inventory/metricdata.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/inventory/core.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/inventory/scripts.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/inventory/ocmcert.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/oui/jlib/OraPrereq.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/oui/jlib/OraCheckPoint.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/oui/jlib/OraInstallerNet.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/oui/jlib/OraInstaller.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/oui/jlib/share.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/oui/jlib/xmlparserv2.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/lib/OCMRFCreator.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/lib/OpsCenterHarvester.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/lib/emCCR.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/lib/emgcharvester.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/lib/emocmclnt-14.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/lib/emocmclnt.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/lib/emocmcommon.jar,\
{file_read}\:/usr/lib/ocm/ccr/lib/emocmdsf.jar
```

Ensure your profile changes are reflected by executing `profiles -l`

Is this just two bugs under Solaris 11.3? One in the `profiles` command (which can be worked around), and the other within the kernel? (Which cannot easily be worked around)

Comment: Can you run the `pfexec` under `truss`?  Something like `truss -f -a -vall -o /some/output/file/name pfexec ...`?

Comment: That's what I was referring to when I said truss reports: `execve("/usr/jdk/instances/jdk1.8.0/bin/java", 0xFCEA4B60, 0xFCEA4B74) Err#79 EOVERFLOW`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why not use wildcards like `{file_read}\:/usr/lib/rad/java/*`?
That will limit the number of entries.  Also, having so many files specifically when we are talking about `{file_read}` will be very expensive.

The number of rules are limited but there is an (undocumented) tunable:
`xpol_rules_max` which you can set in `/etc/system` by adding the line: `set xpol_rules_max=100` or on-the-fly using `mdb -wk` as follows:

```
# mdb -wk
Loading modules: [ unix genunix specfs dtrace mac cpu.generic uppc pcplusmp zvpsm scsi_vhci zfs sata sd ip hook neti arp usba kssl sockfs lofs random idm cpc crypto fcip fctl nfs ufs logindmux ptm sppp ]
> xpol_rules_max/x
xpol_rules_max:
xpol_rules_max: 64
> xpol_rules_max/w 100
xpol_rules_max: 0x64    =       0x100
```

Comment: I didn't use wildcards because I needed to reproduce the issue I was experiencing in a simple to understand example. I'll look into this undocumented tunable today. How expensive are we talking? From what I've seen, Extended Privilege Policy was added in Solaris 11 to allow SELinux type behavior. I suspect I'm ok with as much as a 10% slowdown as long as it guarantees the strict security environment I'm trying to produce.